# module getters not updating in vue component

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vuex

I'an not using getters.js file seperately, instead getters are written in js->assets->store->modules->user.js file

This is my user.js

```
const state = {
    count : '',
    list:[]
};

const mutations = {
    COUNT: (state, data) => {
        state.count = data
    },
    LIST : (state, data) => {
        state.list = data
    }
};

const getters = {
  userCount:(state) => state.list.length
};

const actions = {
    getList: ({commit,state}) => {
        axios.get('/api/user/list')
        .then((response) => {
            commit('LIST', response.data);
        })
    }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

This is my user vue component-user.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
                    <h3>{{ usercount }}</h3>
                    <p>User Registrations</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">View <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    computed: {
        usercount() {
          return this.$store.getters['user/userCount']; 
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('user/getList');
    }
}
</script>
```

In user.js,
    alert(state.list.length)
 gives the correct count in the alert box.

But in user.vue,
    alert(this.$store.getters['user/userCount'])
gives 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Api controller, I'am using paginate() instead of get().vue dev tools helped me to find out this...

```
getList: ({commit,state}) => {
    axios.get('/api/user/list')
    .then((response) => {
        commit('LIST', response.data);
    })
}
```

changed response.data to response.data.data

Answer (score 0):

remove unnecessary `:` from this:

```
const getters = {
  userCount (state) => state.list.length
};
```

Comment: const getters = {
  userCount:(state) => state.list.length
};  this is corrrect.earlier it was showing undefined. But now everything works fine...